# SQL trouble with COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some SQL code that returns me  some data from DB

```
SELECT t1.id as id, title, description FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2  ON t1.id = t2.t1_id 
WHERE t2.t3_id IN( SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE parent_id IN ( SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE parent_id = 1)) GROUP BY t1.id
```

I have some problem with counting number of rows of result. I know that I have to write almost the same code but with COUNT but I have there A problem, my code doesn't return me a number of rows.

Comment: I see no count. Where is it?

Comment: What DBMS? Oracle? SQL Server?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2  ON t1.id = t2.t1_id 
WHERE t2.t3_id IN( SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE parent_id IN ( SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE parent_id = 1)) GROUP BY t1.id

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `COUNT(*)` function. Also, your subqueries can be converted to a `JOIN` (and your sub-subquery is redundant):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.t1_id 
JOIN table3 t2
  ON t3.id = t2.t3_id
WHERE t3.parent_id = 1
```